# Change the size of headings in classicthesis

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, classicthesis

I would like to change the size of the section/- and subsectionheadings in the classicthesis package. I tried to edit sth. in the classicthesis.sty file. There's is a part which has clearly an impact on the headings:

```
% sections \FloatBarrier
    \titleformat{\subsection}
        {\relax}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
% subsections
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\relax}{\textit{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesubsection}}}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}
```

I only managed to change the size with accompanying change of the complete font, like

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
```

Any ideas, how i can change the size without swapping the font-style?

P.S.
I'm a bloody beginner

Comment: Use `\large` instead of (the useless) `\relax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package uses `titleec` to configure the headers, so there is no need to edit the `classicthesis.sty` file.

This example will help you get started.

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text <<<<

%%********************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
% chapters
\renewcommand*{\ct@altfont}{\LARGE\sffamily} % chapter title format <<<<<<<<<<
\DeclareFixedFont{\chapterNumber}{U}{eur}{b}{n}{80} % chapter number size,  was 50
\makeatother

% sections
\titleformat{\section}%
{\normalfont\Large\sffamily} % section title format <<<<<<<<<
{\large\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}%section number format
{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

% subsections
\titleformat{\subsection}% 
{\normalfont\sffamily\itshape}% subsection title format <<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\footnotesize\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesubsection}}} %subsection number format
{1em}{\normalsize}
%%**********************************************    

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Apple}
    
    1. \kant[1]
    \section{Banana}
    2. \kant[2]
    \subsection{Orange}
    4. \kant[9]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!